# PHP - Converting Hours to Mintues

Tags: php, min, hour

I use this site alot and finally I have come across something that I can seem to figure out.  I have a time returned of:

```
"1hr 59min"
```

What I would like it to do is covert this value to Minutes (119).

I havew tried various strtotime methods but none seem to do the trick.  Any ideas?

cheers,

Stu

Comment: Can't you just use hours * 60 + minutes?

Comment: What is your original data?

Comment: I was going to suggest trying `DateInterval::createFromDateString("1hr 59min")`, but it seems that the parser doesn't recognise "hr".  If  that is your input data, you'll have to parse it yourself as per the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a string you could do

```
$onefiftynine = "1hr 59min";
$split        = explode(' ',$onefiftynine);
$hour         = substr($split[0],0,strpos($split[0],'hr'));
$min          = substr($split[1],0,strpos($split[1],'min'));

echo $hour * 60 + $min;
```

Answer (score 0):

Read php docs and use right function, for example http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php , etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you use REGEX, then using preg_replace():

```
$str = '1hr 59min';
$str = preg_replace("/(\d+)hr (\d+)min/e", "$1*60+$2", $str);
// parsing the hour and minute, and doing calculation
```

If your input can have only hr or only min, then add the following two lines with above:

```
$str = preg_replace("/(\d+)hr/e", "$1*60", $str);
$str = preg_replace("/(\d+)min/", "$1", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use a regex :

```
function convertToSeconds($time)
{
    $matches = array();
    if (preg_match('/^(\d+)hr (\d+)min$/', $time, $matches) {
        return $matches[1]*60 + $matches[2];
    }
}
```